# Why does calling quit() before exec() not quit the application?

Tags: qt

Why does this program run normally and display the main window? I would expect it to exit since `quit()` is called in the constructor.

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include<QApplication>
#include"MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
   qApp->quit();
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
{
    qDebug("Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling `QCoreApplication::quit()` is the same as calling `QCoreApplication::exit(0)`.

If you look at the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#exit) of the latter function:

> After this function has been called, the application leaves the main
>   event loop and returns from the call to exec(). The exec() function
>   returns returnCode. **If the event loop is not running, this function
>   does nothing**.

In you example, the event loop has not been started yet when `MainWindow`s constructor is called, hence the call to `quit()` does nothing.

Answer (score 13):

Since `QCoreApplication::quit()` is a no-op until the event loop has been started, you need to defer the call until it starts. Thus, queue a deferred method call to `quit()`.

The following lines are [functionally identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24153731/1329652), either one will work:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
//or
QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, SLOT(quit()));
// or - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/1329652
postToThread([]{ QCoreApplication::quit(); });
// or
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```