# QTimer::singleShot and QMetaMethod::invoke

Tags: qt

In some Qt examples, I see they use 
`QTimer::singleShot(0, this , SLOT(funcA()))`, why not to call the slot `funcA` directly? also the same question for using `QMetaMethod::invoke` to call function with parameters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following lines are all functionally equivalent:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, object, &Class::funcA); // Qt 5
QTimer::singleShot(0, object, SLOT(funcA())); // Qt 4
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "funcA", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

As is now apparent, the intent is to execute the call within the event loop. The queued call results in the posting of an `QMetaCallEvent` to the `object`. This event is handled by `QObject::event` and results in the call of the desired method. Thus, the following are *exactly* equivalent, even if the latter is a private implementation detail - letting me skip [the details of instantiating the event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653558/1329652):

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "funcA", Qt::QueuedConnection);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(object, new QMetaCallEvent{...});
```

This comes handy in various situations. For example:

- To execute some code after all hitherto posted events have been handled.
- To execute only after the event loop has started.
- To call an invokable method that's not accessible due to C++ access modifiers. The invokable methods are: signals, slot, and methods declared `Q_INVOKABLE`.
- The direct call is unsafe (read: an error!) when a `QObject` resides in another thread, unless you're explicitly calling a method documented as thread-safe.

The queued call is a necessity if you wish to ensure that an event loop quits immediately: a direct `quit()` call is a no-op if the loop is not running yet.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  app.quit(); // this is a no-op since the event loop isn't running yet
  return app.exec(); // will not quit as desired
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&app, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
  return app.exec(); // will return immediately
}
```

Ideally, you'd use `postToThread` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646467/how-to-execute-a-functor-in-a-given-thread-in-qt-gcd-style/21653558#21653558), it offers the lowest-cost way of calling methods in other threads:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  postToThread([]{ qApp->quit(); });
}
```

An alternative way of doing it is using a `QObject` as a signal source:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  {
    QObject src;
    src.connect(&src, &QObject::destroyed, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit,
                Qt::QueuedConnection);
  }
  return app.exec(); // will return immediately
}
```

Yet another way would be to use a custom event and act in its destructor:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  struct QuitEvent : QEvent {
    QuitEvent() : QEvent(QEvent::None) {}
    ~QuitEvent() { qApp->quit(); }
  };
  QCoreApplication::postEvent(&app, new QuitEvent);
  return app.exec(); // will return immediately
}
```

Comment: I am getting `QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread` when using QTimer::singleShot in a pure C++ function (not inside a QTthread) while `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` doesn't have this issue. Is there any way to use QTimer::singleShot (or some equivalent method) which supports compile-time checking?

Comment: @Isaac Yes. See the edit. The most efficient and foolproof way of doing it is given in the TL;DR of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646467/how-to-execute-a-functor-in-a-given-thread-in-qt-gcd-style/21653558#21653558).

Answer (score 3):

Every system has a event loop where events are processed. Say like

```
application::processEvents()
{
// process event list..
}
```

Now the place where you write `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(doSomething()));` might be inside some processing event.
When this loop is done, processEvents will be called again and in that the doSomething() will be executed.

So this is like calling doSomething in the next event loop, rather than calling it immediately.
Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Once `QCoreApplication::exec` is entered, your gui thread code is **by definition** executed due to an event (or an asynchronous Unix-signal-like platform-specific mechanism). So it is really obfuscating things to say "might be inside some processing event". Once `app.exec()` is called from `main()`, events are the only reason for *any* UI code to execute, pretty much.

Comment: When you're processing any posted (as opposed to sent) events in Qt, the event loop's event dispatcher is on the call stack somewhere below the ultimate call to `Foo::event(QEvent*)`. When your code finishes, the control returns to the dispatcher, and the dispatcher picks up another event, and invokes the target object's `event(QEvent*)` method again - or goes to sleep waiting for more events to come.

Comment: "events are the only reason for any UI code to execute" disclaimer: Unix signals and Windows I/O completion ports notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

These methods can also be used to invoke protected and private members of a class (if they are defined as slots) from a scope that would otherwise require public access.