# What does QTimer::singleShot(0, object SLOT(obj_slot())) do?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm beginner learning Qt, and trying to understand a Qt provided [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-downloadmanager-example.html) for download operation. In [downloadmanager.cpp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-downloadmanager-downloadmanager-cpp.html), a member function is the following:

```
void DownloadManager::append(const QUrl &url)
{
    if (downloadQueue.isEmpty())
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(startNextDownload()));

    downloadQueue.enqueue(url);
    ++totalCount;
}
```

- I'm confused to why, if `downloadQueue` is empty, it will need to activate the `startNextDownload()` before adding the url. *(note that: `startNextDownload()` ends the program if the `downloadQueue` is empty)*
- I'm unsure why: `QTimer::signleShot(x, y, z)` has been used at all. As I understand it to be, a timer that activates the slot with delay of 0 millisecond.
- I could not figure out from looking at Qt Assistant whether singleShot is a one time setup for repeated activation to the slot at given millisecond interval or whether it is one time

#### Clarification:

I'm a beginner and in examples like:

```
statement1;
statement2;
```

I'm used to seeing `statement1` running and finishing before moving on to working on `statement2`. But trying to learn Qt and reading the given example, I see the `SLOT(startNextDownload())` being activated after `downloadQueue.enqueue(url);` has taken place. I am trying to understand *why* does this work.

Comment: Is QT4 intended? Aren't you using QT5 ?

Comment: I am using Qt 4.8.7.

Comment: okay, just wondering because you're a beginner to qt. Usually beginners would use the newest version I thought :)

Comment: Thanks for this question, ironically it helped me understanding this stuff better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer to current question title

**Every call to `QTimer::singleShot(...)` is executed on the *event loop of the thread where it is invoked* **. If invoked from the main thread, it'll be the event loop started with `app.exec()`.**

According to the Qt-Network-Manager-Example, this function is called *after* the network-manager is filled with the URL's so the single-shot will be processed after the queue has been completely filled. Poorly the qt documentation isn't that clear about this topic yet, so for more information about event processing etc please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142450/qtimersingleshot-and-qmetamethodinvoke).

---

## Answer for old question title

***Before I start, the timer is for having the download in an extra thread. So the GUI keeps responsive.***

The complete `downloadNext()` method is recursive. It will be only called once and called till the queue is empty. 
See this:

```
void DownloadManager::append(const QStringList &urlList)
{
    foreach (QString url, urlList)
        append(QUrl::fromEncoded(url.toLocal8Bit())); //Call for only one URL
  ...
}

void DownloadManager::append(const QUrl &url)
{
    if (downloadQueue.isEmpty())
        //I'm only called if the queue is empty! And I will be called after the next line. Not instantly!
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(startNextDownload()));  

    downloadQueue.enqueue(url);
    ++totalCount;
}
```

After the queue is empty each method returns and at least the message that the download is done will be printed.

**So why does this work?**
Please see first chapter below.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(startNextDownload()));` as a separate thread, how is it guaranteed to run before after `downloadQueue.enqueue(url);` has taken place (given it is only one main thread) ?

Comment: Because it runs on the qt event thread, which starts execution after the call to `app.exec()`

Comment: I am not sure this is correct. AFAIK the slot will run on whatever thread *this* belongs to. This does not have to be the main UI thread (the function will run in the thread of the receiver according to the documentation). So as currently stated the answer is simply wrong.

Comment: Could you refer please to the documentation.

Comment: @ArthurP.R.: See this http://blog.bbv.ch/2012/10/03/multithreaded-programming-with-qt/ blog post for explanation of thread affinity as currently implemented in Qt. Short story - each QObject has thread affinity, queued signal connections maintain the execution in the correct thread automatically

Comment: @EFraim 's right, execution gets scheduled to the QThread's eventloop that "owns" the slot, while `app.exec()` starts the one of the main thread, which in general is a different one.

Answer (score 4):

This queues a callback in the message queue.

The timer immediately elapses, and a message is posted to the message queue. When the process reaches the main loop for the next time, the `startNextDownload()` function is called. By this time, the URL is in the queue.

The `startNextDownload()` function is called from the dispatch context, where it is safe to change window contents. This way, the `DownloadManager` class can be used from a multithreaded application, where the thread starting the download might be running concurrently with the handler for a *Paint* event. By invoking it from the same thread that would handle *Paint* events you can be sure that no such event is being processed, and you can update widgets safely.

If a widget needs to be repainted afterwards, it then asks to be repainted, and the OS will send a *Paint* event if the widget is currently visible.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a bit. Since I have not done any threaded programming, I'm understanding it as pushing it to the queue of things to do which later will be done one by one. 

But why is SLOT(startNextDownload() ensured to run after adding the url to downloadQueue (even though the slot appear/pushed to things to do before the adding) ?

I also don't understand: what is the main loop and what causes a process to reach the main loop?

But I don't know what "When the process reaches the main loop for the next time" means: what is the main loop and what causes it to reach the main loop?

Comment: @RobertC.Holland, wait.. you are right, in a multithreaded application this can stumble over badly. I'd rewrite that as `bool const needToStart = downloadQueue.isEmpty(); downloadQueue.enqueue(url); if(needToStart) QTimer::singleShot(...);`.

Comment: @RobertC.Holland, the main loop is where the program is when it is idle. It's an endless loop where it takes the first event from the queue and handles it, and if there are no events left, it asks the OS to give CPU time to other processes or turn off the CPU until something interesting happens. GUI programs usually consist of just a bunch of event handlers, when they return, the program returns to the main loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm interpreting the program now as such (please correct me if I'm wrong) : `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(startNextDownload()));` tells to add/push onto message queue for the main loop in 0 ms. So, the last thing on the message queue was to run the member function `DownloadManager::append()` (where the singleShot does not make a jump to call the slot but merely schedule to run after) and so, the next thing will be `DownloadManager::startNextDownload()` after `DownloadManager::append()` finishes completely. Thank you!

Comment: **The timer is a lie**. The statement that "timer immediately elapses" is false. `QTimer::singleShot(0, ...)` is a misnomer, it does something totally different than every other invocation of `QTimer::singleShot`. It's a special case that means: "do it next time the event loop gets a go". The time figures nowhere, and the fact that Qt even  internally implements it using handles named "timers" is misleading: those "timers" don't actually use any platform timers, they are simply handles that the event loop uses. A zero-duration timer is-not-a-timer in Qt, in spite of its name.

Comment: It is also not true that the OS sends a repaint event when a widget update is scheduled. That'd be wasteful, as the event loop has all the information needed to invoke the repaint - it doesn't need to wait for the native event queue. When you `QWidget::update`, there are no repaint events coming from the OS. On some platforms, the OS might synchronize the top-level window update with vsync, but Qt itself will perform the update of a backing bitmap ahead of time, and the vsync-triggered action will just copy the bitmap to the screen.

Comment: @KubaOber, these are implementation details that would make the answer more complicated than it needs to be — the behaviour is "as if" the timer immediately elapsed. In the same way, Qt can optimize the path to update widgets if it is safe to do so on the current platform, but some systems do not even have backing bitmaps, so the render target is only available during a paint event. Also, if you modify UI state from outside the main loop, you need an additional lock to synchronize your updates against your other threads.

Comment: The behavior is not "as if" the timer immediately elapsed, although perhaps it's a detail that nobody cares about. `QAbstractEventDispatcher::aboutToBlock` fires only before real timers elapse. I don't know what you mean by "modify the UI state from outside the main loop" - from outside the main thread? Then, yes, the other threads need to have a lock on the main thread's event loop. Unfortunately, Qt doesn't expose that API, but it's a 5-line affair to add it. You can use finer-grained locks, which are preferable when other threads want to keep on working ASAP.

Answer (score -2):

you can understand things about Class QTimer before you end up with a solution as you desire, [please have a look here for your understanding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html)

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't address the question correct.